# jdk7 vs jdk8 adaptive sizing policy differenence

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-8, java-7

I have noticed some difference in the way throughput collector works in java 7 and java 8. I read online both have adaptive size policy turned on by default for throughput.  All major collections in JDK7 is happening when old gen is  full with one big pause lasting for more than 7 seconds. In JDK 8 what I have noticed is there are multiple major collections happening in background lasting for 2-3 seconds. In both the cases I have set Xms(Initial heap) and Xmx(max heap) to same value 8g. We are explicitly providing the size of new gen via newsize and maxnewsize.

What I have read online for adaptive size policy: The JVM automatically adjust upper and lower bound of generations based on the throughput and pause time goals. This link (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Is java7 still has explicit incompatibility for use adaptive sizing with max new size. While java8 does not have such restrictions.

Comment: Could you provide GC logs by enabling "-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:-PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy"? This will provide better insight into what the JVM is doing.

Comment: Is it -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy or -XX:-PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy. I think should be -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy. Please let me know

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's +